# What happened after this time?

Tags: idioms

> Note that the job finished at 17:00:00. I would recommend verifying
>   which steps were taken after this **time**?

How can I ask someone what they did (or which steps they went through) after 17:00:00?

TIA.

[Edit]: For further clarification, this is a batch job that runs on the customer machine. I want to ask the customer what happened after the batch job successfully completed. Did they take any further steps after 17:00:00?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is here. You sort of said it in your question: "What did you do after 5pm?"

Comment: So saying "after this time" makes sense?

Comment: What have you done so far???

Comment: You should use present perfect and the word you're looking for, is **SINCE**, I think.

Comment: So this could work > Note that job finished at 17:00:00. I would recommend verifying which steps were taken **since then**?

Comment: I am quite disappointed to see my question being down-voted. I am simply trying to write the best sentence possible.

Comment: I think it is because the question is difficult to understand. Are you asking for users to log (keep records) of usage after the product was finished and is now in use? If so, tell us why. Perhaps you need to log the number of users, or errors, or successes. Like you, I do not like downvoting -- especially when the person is trying. My response is to not upvote. If we can help you rewrite the question, please let us.

Comment: I added more background information about the question. Thank you for providing feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about:

> Regarding the batch job*  completed at 17:00:00 : Please keep us/me** 
>   updated on any further requirements or adjustments made after
>   completion/submission.

(*number or name of job would be more clear)

(**add your name or department and contact information)

Comment: This is much better than what I originally had! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> I would recommend verifying which steps were taken after this time?

I am not a native English speaker, but I've never heard a native English speaker asking something like that in this way and I think it would sound very odd. First, you've to use the present perfect in this case. Second, if you want to say something very specific, *after* would need a something specific. In your question, *time* doesn't mean anything and it doesn't add any detail to the question you're trying to ask.

> How can I ask someone what they did (or which steps they went through)
>   after 17:00:00?

Possible answers to your question:

**What have you done so far?**

**What have you done since 5 PM (or 17)?**

**Which steps have you been through since 5 PM (or 17)?**

**Note that the job finished at 17. I would recommend verifying which steps have been taken since then.**

**Do you know if any further steps have been taken since then?**